# c++ method binding through templates

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write some templates for wrapping classes into JavaScript. Basically it is done through `SetAccessor ()` specifying a name for the accessor and the member function that must be called. I have created something like this:

```
template <typename Ret, typename T>
void mbind (const char* name, Ret (T::*method)())
{
    ...
    objectTemplate->SetAccessor (String::NewSymbol(name),get_value<Ret,T>);
    ...
}
```

And this is the current definition of `get_value`:

```
template <typename Ret, typename T>
Handle<Value> get_value (Local<String> name, const AccessorInfo& info)
{
    ...
}
```

The idea is to automatically bind the function in the following way:

```
mbind ("getX",&SomeClass::getX);
```

But this won't work if I have two methods like this:

```
int SomeClass::getX ();
int SomeClass::getY ();
```

since `Ret` and `T` are the same in both cases. How can I get different template instantiations for these two cases?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pointer to member as an additional template parameter (no time to test the code right now, sorry):

```
template <class Ret, class T, Ret (T::* method)()>
void mbind(const char* name)
{
   .... get_value<Ret, T, method>() ...
}

template <typename Ret, typename T, Ret (T::* method)()> 
Handle<Value> get_value (Local<String> name, const AccessorInfo& info) 
{
    ....
}

mbind<int, SomeClass, &SomeClass::GetX>("GetX");
```

### EDIT

It seems I have more time: the following is a bit better I guess since it will allow any kind of arguments and reduce the number of parameters:

```
template <class MethodT, MethodT method>
void mbind(const char* name)
{
    .... get_value<MethodT, method>() ....
}

template <class MethodT, MethodT method> 
Handle<Value> get_value (Local<String> name, const AccessorInfo& info) 
{
    ....
}

mbind<int (SomeClass::*)(), &SomeClass::GetX>("GetX");
```

Comment: I have already tried it but it doesn't work. 
`error: ‘method’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘int (Cell::*)()’
error: it must be a pointer-to-member of the form &X::Y'`
I think it doesn't work as I'm trying to pass a function parameter (which is a variable) as a template argument.

Comment: It does work on my compiler (the two I posted). Which compiler are you using ?

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.5.2: `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2`

Comment: I am on GCC 4.6.1 (ubuntu as well). Please post the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

N., sorry for my late reply. I have tried two solutions more based on what you said and neither of them work:

solution 1:

```
template <typename Ret, typename T, Ret(T::*mptr)()>
Handle<Value> get_value (Local<String> name, const AccessorInfo& info)
{
    ...
}


template <typename Ret, typename T>
void mbind (const char* name, Ret (T::*mptr)())
{
    ....
    objectTemplate->SetAccessor (String::NewSymbol (name),get_value<Ret,T,mptr>);
```

}

solution 2:

```
template <typename M, M mptr>
Handle<Value> get_val (Local<String> name, const AccessorInfo& info)
{
    ...
}


template <typename Ret, typename T>
void register_get_mem_fun (const char* name, Ret(T::*mptr)())
{
    v8::HandleScope localScope;

    typedef Ret (T::*M)();

    ....

    objectTemplate->SetAccessor (String::NewSymbol (name),get_val<M,mptr>);
}
```

In both cases the error is essentially the same:

```
wrapper.h:184:5: error: ‘mptr’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘int (Cell::*)()’
wrapper.h:184:5: error: it must be a pointer-to-member of the form `&X::Y'
```